# Starting Cassandra from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, cassandra

I'm trying to start a Cassandra instance (0.8.10) from Jenkins (latest version, 1.463).

Inside a "free-style project" job, I have a "Execute shell" build step, where I have tried a couple of approaches:

```
.../tools/apache-cassandra-0.8.10/bin/cassandra -f
```

and

```
.../tools/apache-cassandra-0.8.10/bin/cassandra
```

The first approach starts Cassandra ok, but Jenkins doesn't exit the build and keeps on building. If I stop the build, the Cassandra process dies as well.

The second approach fails because the Cassandra project dies as soon as the build finishes.
I have also tried:

```
.../tools/apache-cassandra-0.8.10/bin/cassandra -f &
```

that is kind of lame, and doesn't work anyway.

Any ideas on how to start Cassandra from Jenkins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using nohup with `&`. Also pipe stdout and stderr to a file or /dev/null:

```
nohup .../tools/apache-cassandra-0.8.10/bin/cassandra -f > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &
```

Comment: Actually, I have tried that, it doesn't work. It seems that there is a problem in jenkins with spawned processes: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller

Comment: if I use "export BUILD_ID=dontKillMe" it kinda works. The build fails but the Cassandra process is started

Comment: So you did solve your problem, didn't you? Please provide it as an answer, then. Also, maybe what you really need is [monitoring an external job](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Monitoring+external+jobs).

Comment: not really, as the build is marked as failed, even though the process is actually started

Comment: Can you then please update your question with that info and also include build console output?